# Excel - get first record of data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple problem, yet I am finding it difficult to find an easy solution.

I have a dataset of students attempting a test. I get a record of student id, test outcome and date of sitting. Example below.

I would like to count the number of students that passed FIRST time, without having to order the data as my dataset is very large.

[image]

I would appreciate any input.

Many thanks

Comment: In your posted example, the data is ordered by **date**, is this the case for the full data ??

Comment: No -- this screenshot is for demo purposes only.

Comment: Do all students write their first attempt on the same date?

Comment: No it is not...

Comment: Perhaps you could pivot min(date) by student, then lookup the date and student and see if it is marked as PASSED or FAILED? Or work out a way of counting students who only took the exam once and passed (because if they passed it wouldn't make sense to take the exam again - or would it - maybe they want to re-take the exam and improve their marks?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I had thought about this a bit more, I realised that you only need to count how many instances there were where someone had passed, and there were no exams for the same person with an earlier date. The only assumption is that you can't take the same exam twice in the same day, which I think is reasonable.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B11="Passed")*(COUNTIFS(A2:A11,A2:A11,C2:C11,"<"&C2:C11)=0))
```

I have changed John's first result to "Failed" to show that it isn't counted.

[image]

Here is the same method broken down into steps with helper columns:

[image]

D2 is just

```
=B2="Passed"
```

E2

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,C$2:C$11,"<"&C2)
```

F2

```
=E2=0
```

G2

```
=D2*F2
```

remembering that TRUE*TRUE=1 and any other combination of true and false=0.

So the various scenarios are

(1) In row 2, John failed so the result in G2 is 0 although he has no previous exams

(2) In row 3, George has passed and has no previous exams so the result in G3 is 1

(3) In row 5, John has now passed but has taken previous exams so the result in G5 is still 0.

The SUMPRODUCT is effectively an array formula. When the criteria in a countifs are themselves ranges like A2:A11 and C2:C11, the countifs is re-evaluated for each pair of cells in the range (A2,C2 then A3,C3 etc.) and produces an array of results exactly like column E above, so when multiplied by B2="Passed" it gives the same results as in column G2 above and adds them together to give the final count.

Comment: This is great - can you explain to me how this formula works?

Comment: Will add to my answer.

Comment: Awesome as always Tom

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I tried on your sample data:

[image]

Formula in cell `E2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((B2:B11="Passed")*(C2:C11=MINIFS(C2:C11,A2:A11,A2:A11)),MATCH(A2:A11,A2:A11,0)),ROW(A2:A11)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

Entered as array using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

To be honest, I wouldn't call this a simple problem :). Curious to see if there are other direct ways.